# Return count of 1's preceding 0's for each group and each zero within group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i work on a big data file (10 millions rows), here is the two columns i care about for now:

```
|    id    |       v1       |
| 101      | 0              |
| 101      | 0              |
| 101      | 1              |
| 101      | 0              |
| 101      | 1              |
| 101      | 1              |
| 101      | 0              |
| 101      | 1              |
| 97       | 0              |
| 97       | 1              |
| 97       | 1              |
| 97       | 0              |
| 97       | 0              |
| 13       | 1              | 
| 13       | 1              |
| 13       | 0              |
| 13       | 1              |
| 13       | 0              |
| 13       | 1              |
| 13       | 1              |
| 13       | 1              |
| 13       | 1              |
| 13       | 0              |
| 2076     | 0              |
| 2076     | 0              |
| 2076     | 0              |
```

...

i want to create a column (with a smaller size),  that contains how many `1` precedes each `0` in the `v1` column, for each `id` . for example the result for `id=101` will be like:

| the now column |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |

I tried to do this with nested loops but it failed, i stopped the execution after 10 hours of run. and i'm looking for fast alternatives.

thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the 2 be a 3? Also could you add the full expected output?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I think they only want to count the 1s that occurred before the current 0 but only after the previous 0 (i.e., the 1s between the 0s).

Comment: Great question and welcome to StackOverflow! Kindly accept the best answer if it has solved your problem by clicking the checkmark next to the answer (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ). Happy Holidays!

Comment: @DaniMesejo, no, only the ones coming after the previous zero .. is just like the output below by David Erickson,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal below is to create groups, which you can do by grouping all `0` and preceding `1` values into a "subgroup" and take the `size() - 1` (minus 1 to subtract the counting of each zero in each subgroup):

```
z = df1['v1'].eq(0) # return True for values equal to 0

# if True return cumulative sum, else nan
df1['subgroup'] = np.where(z, z.cumsum(), np.nan) 

# backfill what is essentially the "subgroup" for `0` values to `1` values that belong with each subgroup.
df1['subgroup'] = df1.groupby('id')['subgroup'].bfill()

# groupby id and subgroup, get the size of the group, subtract 1 and drop the subgroup from output with droplevel(1) since 2nd column of index
df1 = (df1.groupby(['id', 'subgroup'], sort=False).size() - 1).droplevel(1)

df1

Out[1]: 
id
101     0
101     0
101     1
101     2
97      0
97      2
97      0
13      2
13      1
13      4
2076    0
2076    0
2076    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you, this is an elegant answer, i had an issue when i tried to write it as a function (it gaves me oom error), but it works otherwise.